# using C# in markup to get value from a datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, markup

I want to start off by saying I am not sure how to properly word what I am aiming to do, so there may be plentiful examples on how to do what I am trying to do, I just cannot find them.
That being said my explanation might be a bit wordy so I appreciate any and all help.

I am including a new feature on a previously created .Net webpage and sql database.   The code currently returns a DataSet from the database and binds it to a datagrid.   From there it is loaded into a table on the webpage.   What my new column needs to do is take the primarykey from the current row and use it to call a stored procedure to get more data.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="siteAdmin" HeaderText="SITE ADMIN">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# listAdmin("siteAdmin", ***issue is here*** ) %>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

The code in the markup calls a method that calls the stored procedure I need to retrieve the string I am looking for.  The issue I am having is figuring out how to get the primarykey, which is an int into the second parameter of the listAdmin() method. The primarykeys for each row are returned from the database in a column of the dataSet called "trackingId"

Any help would be gratefully received.   If I can clear anything up, please ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="siteAdmin" HeaderText="SITE ADMIN">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# listAdmin("siteAdmin", Eval("trackingId")) %>'>
    </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: that worked like a charm!  i just had to cast it to an int  - (int)Eval("trackingId")   Ive been working on this problem for many hours,  i could kiss you!